# Proper way to enforce string validation on length with space padding

Tags: c#, string, validation, csv, properties

I have to generate a csv file from my db.  I am using C# and I can do this.  My question is more to do with validation.  I was thinking of doing this:

```
public class MyObject
{
 private string myString;
 public string MyString
 {
   get
   {
     return this.myString;
   }
   set
   {
     this.myString = value.Remove(15).PadRight(15);
   }
}
```

Obviously 15 is the max length on this field.  Is this an idiotic way to handle this?  I am open to suggestions.  This is just the tip of the iceberg for this program that will be generating numerous different csv's and I want to make sure I set up a sustainable pattern.

Comment: If the data is coming from your database, and your database has the correct field lengths defined, why do this at all? Do you need to export in fixed length format?

Comment: This example in my opinion is not necessary it could actually cause more errors than expects based on this example as well as the single answer that was provided below.. Refacted Paladin if you want to create a .csv file from a DB there are easier ways of doing so getting records from DB via a Query then build the header in a List<string> there is a Method that will return Column Headers then from there you can build a separate List<string> holding your Comma Delim fields, then before adding the first row just append the data from header list to DataList for example ..I've done this 1000 times

Comment: @Oded Yup, I am exporting in Fixed Length CSV.  The fields in the DB are not neccesarily the same size.  i.e. AddressLine1 in DB is 50 but in the Extract it's 25.

Comment: Can you not use a third party library like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)? Can make this kind of export real easy.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I understand and maybe I'm missing something but the Extract is not reflected by our DB.  The values come from it, sure, but the structure, field name, field length, etc are all dictated on a Definitions file by a 3rd Party that I have to submit these too.

Comment: @Oded That's exactly what I am using, FileHelpers, but that doesn't help me with the length issue, at least to my knowledge, as it doesn't support any concept of Attribute marking in that respect.  Wonderful library though.

Comment: Well, with fixed length, it should take care of things for you. It certainly handled fixed lengths.

Comment: Except I need a fixed length comma deliminated.....weird huh....

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this pattern is that you're going to miss any bad records because you're swallowing the exception by simply massaging the data. However, if that's what you want then it's perfect.

Another approach would be to push these records to an error list and let the user determine what to do with them after it's all done. So, you could do something like this:

```
public sealed class BadRecords
{
    private static BadRecords _instance;
    public static BadRecords Instance
    {
        if (_instance == null) { _instance = new BadRecords(); }
        return _instance;
    }

    private BadRecords() { this.List = new List<MyObject>(); }

    public List<MyObject> List { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
 private string myString;
 public string MyString
 {
   get
   {
     return this.myString;
   }
   set
   {
     if (value.Length > 15) { BadRecords.Instanse.List.Add(this); }
     else { this.myString = value.Remove(15).PadRight(15); }
   }
}
```

however, there is still one problem with your solution, you're not really just taking the first 15 characters. In fact, the code you have would error on a string less than 15 characters. Consider something more like this:

```
this.myString = value.Length > 15 ? value.Substring(0, 15) : value;
```

if you're insistent on swallowing the error.

However, in the solution I provided you could simply use this:

```
this.myString = value.PadRight(15);
```

because we've already checked to see if it's greater than 15 characters.

Comment: I really like this idea. Thanks.  Question, if I go your route with the `? :` :) method would I then do the padding on a seperate line?  Seems like I could just do this,`this.myString = value.Length > 15 ? value.Substring(0,15) : value.PadRight(15)` , right?

Comment: @RefractedPaladin, yes that's all you would need because if the length is greater than 15 you **know** that you can grab the first 15, but if it's not you know you just want the **raw** string padded.